# Unable to upload file using BoxView

Tags: box-view-api

I have created a Box View application. Now I am trying to upload a document using below POST request:

[image: POST Request configuration]

When I run the above request, I get “Invalid API token error”. Refer snapshot below:

[image: Error details]

I think I am using the right API key that is provided when the Box view App was created. Please refer below screenshot:

[image: API Token]

What could be the issue here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the incorrect base URL. You have

```
https://crocodoc.com/api/v2/
```

but the base URL for the Box View API is

```
https://view-api.box.com/1/
```

Please see the documentation for more details: http://developers.box.com/view/